# Nodejs Post to Neo4j UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning & DeprecationWarning errors

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I am using NodeJs v8.9.4 & Neo4j 3.5.5. My neo4j database is on Graphenedb & my app is on Heroku, but the issue exists on my local app and db as well.

Up until last week, the code below has been working with no problem at all. I have been able to post to my neo4j database using my nodejs app.

Problem: When I use my app to post or create a new node in neo4j, I receive the following errors:

(node:12184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: err is not defined

(node:12184) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
POST /beer/add - - ms - -

Again, I have never seen these errors until last week.

I can Get and read data from my neo4j db into my app no problem. I've tried running the same Post from my local app to a local neo4j db. Again, this used to work no problem, up until last week, but it won't work locally either. My code has not changed at all. I can provide more of my server.js code or index.ejs code if necessary.

```
server.js file
const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost:7687', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j','neo4j'));


//Post to create beer node
app.post('/beer/add', async (req, res) => {
  const {beername, abv, ibu, rating, beertypename, breweryname} = req.body;
  try {
    const result = await session.run('Match (bt:BeerType {name: {beertypenameParam}}), (bry:Brewery {name: {brewerynameParam}}) Create (bt)<-[r:IS_A]-(b:Beer {name: {beernameParam},ABV:{abvParam},IBU:{ibuParam},Rating:{ratingParam}})<-[r2:BREWS]-(bry) Set b.date = apoc.date.format(timestamp(),"ms","MM/dd/yyyy"),b.Uid = apoc.create.uuid() Return bt,b,bry', {beertypenameParam:beertypename,brewerynameParam:breweryname,beernameParam:beername, abvParam:abv, ibuParam:ibu, ratingParam:rating})
    if (result) {
      res.redirect('/');
      session.close()
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(err)
  };
});
```

I expect the //Post to create beer node code above to create a new node/object, but it does not. However, I can still create relationships/edges using my app. For example, executing the following code to create a relationship between 2 nodes/objects in my app works fine...

```
server.js file
//Post to create relationship between beer and seller
app.post('/beer/seller/add',async (req, res) => {
  const {beername, sellername} = req.body;
  try {
    const result = await session.run('Match (b:Beer {name:{beernameParam}}),(s:Seller {name:{sellernameParam}}) Create (b)-[r:PURCHASED_FROM]->(s) Return b,s', {beernameParam:beername, sellernameParam:sellername});
    if (result) {
      res.redirect('/');
      session.close()
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(err)
  };
});
```

How can I fix my //Post to create beer node code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(err)
  };
```

This will generate a syntax error when run - `err` is not defined, but `e` is. I'm guessing up until the past week, your code has never generated an error that has been caught by the `try/catch`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, jakemingolla, ok using the `console.log(e)` actually allowed my console.log to display the real error.